# Converting Column data types

Tags: r, dataset, lubridate

I'm working on a college project with R and the data I'm using has defined its date and time as a character column. I wanted to change this to a datetime with lubridate since the column characters are formatted as 01-01-2019 00:00:00.

Any help with this would be great as I'm entirely lost.

edit just to better specificy: I want to change the entire tables values not just a single one so i can use the dates to track the data in a plot. I'm adding an image of the table below as well.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ali8.png)

Comment: This is an R question. It has nothing to do with RStudio.

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.  In particular do NOT use images for input data since no one wants to have to retype all that.  Use `dput`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the input is month-day-year hours:minutes:seconds use one of these depending on what you want.  The output of the second one will be slightly different if you are in a different time zone.

```
library(lubridate)

mdy_hms("01-01-2019 00:00:00")
## [1] "2019-01-01 UTC"

mdy_hms("01-01-2019 00:00:00", tz = "")
## [1] "2019-01-01 EST"
```

The question asked for datetime using lubridate which is what is provided above but if all your datetimes are just dates with 0 times then you would be better off using Date class to avoid the possibility of having to worry about time zones and the subtle errors that can accompany the use of them.  This uses only base R. `as.Date` will ignore the `00:00:00` junk at the end.

```
as.Date("01-01-2019 00:00:00", "%m-%d-%Y")
## [1] "2019-01-01"
```

Comment: This is great for just a single value but I want to translate the entire column that contains the date ( I've added a screenshot to the post for reference) since I'm tryna plot the other data against the dates showing the rise and falls

Comment: You need to fix the question. See my comments under the question but what you want is something like this: `df %>% mutate(x = mdy_hms(x))`